# How to divide an array into three different parts?

Tags: java, arrays

Okay hello everyone, im pretty new to java programming and im really having trouble with arrays. My program its supposed to read a .txt file that contains 3 numbers per line (its a problem about calories, the first number means breakfast, the second one lunch, and the third one dinner)

So I create an Array.list (calories) because it will read from the file with unknown length. So far, it worked now I put the values into an array, but I want to split this array in three single dimensional arrays. An array for the values of breakfast, another one for lunch and the last one for dinner.

My problem is I just cant figure out how to divide the length of the main array to assign the size to each of my other 3 different arrays. (I tried something like array.length / 3, but it gave me an error of IndexOutOfBounds) I know its pretty messy and everything :( but I barely get this, if you could give me at least an idea I will be very thankful !

```java
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class lab {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    readData("ARRAYLAB1.txt");   //read file arraylab1.txt
}
static void readData(String filename) {
    try {

        List<Integer> calories = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
        // Defining an integer Array List

        Scanner myfile = new Scanner(new FileReader("ARRAYLAB1.txt")); 
        // Reading file using Scanner

        while (myfile.hasNext()) {     
            calories.add(myfile.nextInt());   // Read file content using a while loop
            } 

        int[] array = new int[calories.size()];    //Pass the array list to an array
        for(int i = 0; i < calories.size(); i++) 
            array[i] = calories.get(i);


       int size = array.length / 3;  //This didn't work 

       int[] breakfast = new int[size];   <---  index out of bounds error 
       int[] lunch = new int[size];
       int[] dinner = new int[size]; 


       //the rest just assigns each value to their respective array 
        int counter = 1;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (counter == 1) {
                breakfast[j] = array[i]; 
                counter++;
                j++;
                continue;
                }
            if (counter == 2) {
                lunch[k] = array[i]; 
                counter++;
                k++;
                continue;
            }
            if (counter == 3) {
                dinner[x] = array[i]; 
                counter = 1; 
                x++;
                continue;
            }
        }


        myfile.close(); // close the file


    }  catch (Exception e) {     // Defined it just in the case of error
        e.printStackTrace();   
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: If you do a System.out.println(size) before that out of bounds error what do you get?

Comment: That's the weird thing I actually get the size, and also if I do calories.size() / 3. Idk why am I getting the error at the moment of giving the size to the other arrays.

Comment: Can you try `int size = (int)(array.length/3);` and see if it gets any better!!

Comment: I just tested your code and it worked successfully. Could you list your java version and error log.

Comment: Is array.length always a multiple of 3? If it is not you need to round up (ceil) while dividing by 3

Comment: Nope still getting index out of bounds :/

Comment: @MattQuinlan where did you tested it? I am using eclipse

Comment: yes its always a multiple of 3 because the text has every day divided into 3 meals

Comment: How can you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in array initialization?

Comment: I assume this is an exercise from a book or your class? Does it specifically tell you to use an ArrayList or will there always be the same number of days in the file? It seems to me like you've overcomplicated things. It might also help if you posted the contents of your file.

Comment: Also, in your `readData` function, you seem to be hardcoding the filename instead of using the `filename` argument. Not related to your bug; just an observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archit hit the nail on the head. If you don't have an exact multiple of three, your index out of bounds actually occurs when you assign the values to the (breakfast/lunch/dinner) array. To avoid this, you could use a dynamically sized array called an array list (like you used for calories). And avoid the divide by 3 issue.

The code then becomes:

```
List<Integer> calories = new ArrayList<Integer>();  

Scanner myfile = new Scanner(new FileReader("ARRAYLAB1.txt")); 

while (myfile.hasNext()) {     
    calories.add(myfile.nextInt());   // Read file content using a while loop
} 

List<Integer> breakfast = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> lunch = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> dinner = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//the rest just assigns each value to their respective array 
int counter = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < calories.size(i); i++) {
    if (counter == 1) {
        breakfast.add(calories.get(i)); 
        counter++;
        continue;
    }
    if (counter == 2) {
        lunch.add(calories.get(i)); 
        counter++;
        continue;
    }
    if (counter == 3) {
        dinner.add(calories.get(i)); 
        counter = 1; 
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting/alignment. I'm still relatively new to answering on this site. I've gotten a lot from this site and thought I should start trying to give back...

Comment: "Sorry for the poor formatting/alignment" As long as you go back and try to fix the formatting instead of leaving it as poor, no worries.

Comment: @MattQuinlan yes!! that work oh god thank you so much ! If I could buy you a cake I would :D! thaaaank youuuu :D

Comment: @DennisMeng I tried to fix it. I think it looks ok now. I'm guessing its easiest to copy code into your own IDE, edit there, and then paste back?

Answer (score 1):

size has to be an int value. when you get index out of bound exception simply add the size variable in the watch window to validate that you indeed have an integer value for it. Better Round off the size value to become an integer, since division by 3 will not give you integer value when it is not a multiple of 3. You can cast it to integer as well.

If your length value is multiple of 3, your code should work fine.

Comment: Yes it will, an int divided by an int results in another int.